# Show $g^s\in L^1((0,1),\mathbb{R})$ for $s≤1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $g:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $g(x)=\frac1{x(1-\ln(x))^2}$. Show that $g^s\in L^1((0,1),\mathbb{R})$ for $s ≤ 1$ and $g^s\notin L^1((0,1),\mathbb{R})$ for $s > 1$.

So for this I tried looking at the singular cases:

For $s=0$ : trivial.

For $s=1$ : $\int^1_0g(x) dx = \big[\frac1{1-\ln(x)}\big]^1_0=1$

For $s=-1$ : $\int^1_0g(x)^{-1} dx=\int^1_0x(1-\ln(x))^2=$ (after long computation) $= \frac54$

I tried also for $s=2$ but it takes too much computation and time, I don't think it's the objective of this exercise.

I know the singular cases are not enough, and I should find something to show it holds for all s,
but in my theory there is not anything about power of functions neither examples. Do you have any hint/tricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to compute the integrals explicitly; it is enough to show that the integrals are (in)finite depending on the value of $s$. One approach is to compare the integrals $\int_{(0,1)} |g(x)|^s \, dx$ with integrals of the form $\int_{(0,1)} x^{\beta} \, dx$ for suitably chosen $\beta$.

**Case 1: $s \in [0,1)$:** Since $\ln(x) \to - \infty$ as $x \to 0$, we have $(1-\ln(x))^2 \to \infty$ as $x \to 0$. In particular, $$|g(x)|^s = \frac{1}{x^s} \frac{1}{(1-\ln x)^{2s}} \leq \frac{1}{x^s}$$ for small $x>0$, say, for $x \in (0,r)$. Consequently, $$\int_{(0,r)} |g(x)|^s \, dx \leq \int_{(0,r)} \frac{1}{x^s} \, dx \stackrel{s<1}{<} \infty.$$ Noting that $g$ is continuous, hence bounded, on $[r,1]$, we also get $\int_{[r,1]} |g(x)|^s \, dx < \infty$, and so, in conclusion, $g \in L^s((0,1))$.

**Case 2: $s>1$:** The exponential function grows faster than any polynomial. This implies that we can find for every $\epsilon>0$ some constant $C=C(\epsilon)$ such that $|\ln(x)| \leq C x^{-\epsilon}$ for small $x$, say $x \leq r=r(\epsilon)$. This implies

$$g(x) \geq \frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{(2 \ln(x))^2} \geq \frac{1}{C^2} \frac{1}{x} x^{2\epsilon}$$

for small $x$. Consequently,

$$\int_{(0,1)} |g(x)|^s \, dx \geq \frac{1}{C^2} \int_{(0,r)} \frac{1}{x^s} x^{2\epsilon s} \, dx.$$

As $s>1$, we can choose $\epsilon>0$ small enough such that $2\epsilon s < \frac{1-s}{2}$. Then $s-2\epsilon s>1$, and therefore $\int_{(0,r)} \frac{1}{x^s} x^{2\epsilon s} \, dx=\infty$. Thus, $g \notin L^s((0,1))$ for $s>1$.